# Elimination Drop down dependency from jquery & .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

[image]I am looking to eliminate the dropdown list dependency.
How do I eliminate the .change function from my html without breaking the code. 
I want the graph to load without a selection from the dropdown and I don't want the dropdown but the html is tied to this.
Here is where I obtained the code:
https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel

Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>D3 Funnel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="httpmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.combootstrap3.3.4cssbootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>D3 Funnel</h1>
            <div class="example">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <select class="form-control" id="picker">
                        <option value="basic">No options</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
                <!-- Funnel container -->
                <div id="funnel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Required D3 library -->
        <script src="httpcdnjs.cloudflare.comajaxlibsd33.5.5d3.js"></script>
        <!-- D3Funnel source file -->
        <script src="d3-funnel.js"></script>

        <!-- Just for the example -->
        <script src="httpcode.jquery.comjquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#picker').change(function() {
                    var index = $(this).val();

                    var data = {
                        normal: [
                            ['Applicants',   100],
                            ['Pre-screened', 400],
                            ['Interviewed',  250],
                            ['Hired',        150],
                            ['Fired',        205]
                        ],
                    };

                    var options = {
                        basic: [data.normal, {
                            fillType: 'gradient',
                            dynamicArea: true
                        }],
                    };

                    var chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');

                        chart.draw(options[index][0], options[index][1]);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your script block with the following block

```
var index = 'basic';
var data = {
    normal: [
        ['Applicants',   100],
        ['Pre-screened', 400],
        ['Interviewed',  250],
        ['Hired',        150],
        ['Fired',        205]
    ],
};

var options = {
    basic: [data.normal, {
        fillType: 'gradient',
        dynamicArea: true
    }],
};

var chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
chart.draw(options[index][0], options[index][1]);
```

and you can remove the reference to jQuery.

Comment: Now how would I add a dialog box so when I click on segment of the funnel it would provide additional information? Such as if I clicked Applicants, a dialog would pop up (like a alert box) and would tell me of the 100 applicants, 50 where engineers and 50 where Sales ppl                        --  Thanks  --

Comment: You should be using `onItemClick` - see https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel and show the dialog on the onclick event. For showing a neat dialog (instead of an alert box) you'll be better off looking at a library - it will messy to roll your own.

Comment: Such as using jQuery? According to  github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel the  `onItemClick` is linked to a function `function(d,i){}` This is what I have for js https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AKTybwR3U9

Comment: I don't think jQuery has dialogs - you would need jQuery UI too. I'm pretty sure there'll be other smaller libraries that just do dialogs if you are just building 1 page (otherwise you'll have to make the choice of library considering the rest of your site's requirements). The fiddle you linked to seems to be a collaboration session - could you create a plain one instead? Cheers!